# How to send different data depending on the number entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code.

```
function updateQuantityCatalog(update) {
// take some DATA
        id = $(update).attr('data-id');
        if ($('div').is('card')) {
            detail = 'Y';
            quant = $(update).parent().find('input').val();
        } else {
            detail = '';
            quant = 1;
        }
// ALL ATTENSION HERE
// depending on the button being pressed, different data is sent
        if ($(update).hasClass('minus')) {
            type = 'del';
        } else {
            type = 'add';
        }
        $.ajax({ bla bla ajax request });
    }
```

How i can send this "del" or "add" if i self type in input value?

Comment: Add your HTML and explain more your problem.

Comment: You are already 99% there. Just build `bla bla` according to what you want to send. Only you know how to do that.